# Removing the CSS file

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring MVC with jsp page for presentation, i have three tab suppose **A,B** and **C** in one jsp page. While clicking on A tab the css file such as aa.css have being loading in head tag with respective div is shown and the same way on click on B and C. The main problem is once the **Three** .**CSS** file is being loaded it overwrite each other. Also i want to remove **css** file from **head** which has being loaded on click of any of above tab using **jquery** as shown below.

```
  $("#A").click(function(){
     alert("Remove bb and cc.css file form head tag");
  });
```

any idea will help me lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you need this because removing CSS file tage after loading the document is of no use

Comment: no on click of any of tab the respective css file will be loaded again. The problem is that this 3 css file have some common classes  due to which other css gets effected.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Give an `id` to the `<link>` tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" id="style1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" id="style2" />
```

And use this **code**:

```
$("#A").click(function(){
    $("#style1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

**Note:** While there is no disabled attribute in the HTML standard, there is a disabled attribute on the HTMLLinkElement DOM object.

The use of disabled as an HTML attribute is non-standard and only used by some Microsoft browsers. Do not use it. To achieve a similar effect, use one of the following techniques:

- If the `disabled` attribute has been added directly to the element on the page, do not include the `<link>` element instead;
- Set the `disabled` property of the DOM object via scripting.

Answer (score 7):

You can unload a css by disabling it as follows:

```
$("#A").click(function(){
    $("link[href*=bb.css]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("link[href*=cc.css]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("link[href*=aa.css]").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: use removeAttr('disabled') for that css

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=./css/manage_deals.css] i am using as $("link[href=./css/manage_deals.css]").attr("disabled");

Comment: Thanks @MdToufiqulIslam - inspired by your answer I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60150725/3749432)

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable css files without being able to specify an id, so to remove the following css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8092/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" disabled="disabled">
```

I added this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('link[href*="bootstrap.min.css"]').attr("disabled", "true");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just give that link tag an id or a class (say id="deleteMe") then remove it like below:

```
$('head').find('link#deleteMe').remove();
```

So in your case add id to each file when you link them like this:

```
<link id="aa" rel="stylesheet" href="First.css" type="text/css" />  
<link id="bb" rel="stylesheet" href="Second.css" type="text/css" />  
<link id="bb" rel="stylesheet" href="Third.css" type="text/css" />
```

Now to remove only Second.css, Third.css you have to write your jQuery like this:

```
(function ($) {  
    $('head').find('link#aa').remove();  
    $('head').find('link#bb').remove();  
})(jQuery);
```