# Prevent page from loading masterpage css

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms

I'm looking for the correct way to prevent my webform page from loading the css from the master page.

Atm I'm overriding the css page by including another css file in the page head:

```
<link href="customStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But this doesn't stop the loading of my master.css. Only overrides it.
I assume there is a way to stop prevent inheritance of mastpage css.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not remove that external css file after page load that way the content effect won't take place?

Comment: Please Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857734/removing-the-css-file) . This can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below line as you first line of code, to remove the css !

```
$("[href='masterStyle.css']").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more complicated than I'd like, but how I solved the problem.

Note I am using VB.Net in my code.

Add to your MasterPage a property, make sure it is public. In this example I named it HideCSS:

```
Public Property HideCSS As Boolean
  Get
    Return ViewState("mybool")
  End Get
  Set(value As Boolean)
    ViewState("mybool") = value
  End Set
End Property
```

Then in the .master markup page have something like this:

```
<% If Not HideCSS Then%>
  <link href="customStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<% End If%>
```

This way the css will always render unless HideCSS is explicitly updated to False.

Then in your page using the master page, code similar to the following:

```
'TODO Add error checking if necessary
Dim master = TryCast(Me.Master, {MasterPagesClassName}) 
master.HideCSS = true
```

Make sure you replace {MasterPagesClassName} with the actual class name of your master page file's code-behind.