# How can I get rid of extra CSS content

Tags: css, node.js, npm

I have been working with a large project with many others. Unfortunately (but realistically) there is a ton of extra CSS such as the body element declaring the same font over and over.

I'm looking for possibly an NPM plugin or something that takes out extra content like that. Does anyone know of plugin like this or another solution?

Comment: So, did you mean specific CSS selectors or all of them?

Comment: All of them. There are many different classes that are restyled with the same attribute. I know an IDE or DevTools would tell me where its being restyled, but there are a lot.

Comment: Well... You can disable CSS files which were imported using `link` element. Here is the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857734/removing-the-css-file). Or you are able to use `*` selector for all element and add the style you are annoyed with `!important` if it those CSS files can stay in HTML.